# Are Socket.*Async methods threaded?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I'm currently trying to figure what is the best way to minimize the amount of threads I use in a TCP master server, in order to maximize performance.

As I've been reading a lot recently with the new async features of C# 5.0, asynchronous does not necessarily mean multithreaded. It could mean separated in smaller chunks of finite state objects, then processed alongside other operations, by alternating. However, I don't see how this could be done in networking, since I'm basically "waiting" for input (from the client).

Therefore, I wouldn't use ReceiveAsync() for all my sockets, it would just be creating and ending threads continuously (assuming it *does* create threads).

Consequently, my question is more or less: what architecture can a master server take without having one "thread" per connection?

Side question for bonus coolness points: Why is having multiple threads bad, considering that having an amount of threads that is over your amount of processing cores simply makes the machine "fake" multithreading, just like any other asynchronous method would?

Comment: answer to side: scheduling takes time.

Comment: As this is obviously a more theoretical question, could you develop on the concept of scheduling and provide comparisons? Thanks. :)

Comment: I can't, not really an expert on the subject. But I mean, the act of balancing out the workload between threads is probably a pretty complex algorithm - its not just switching in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the `*Async` methods use IOCP (by looking at the code with Reflector).

Answer (score 8):

No, you would not necessarily be creating threads. There are two possible ways you can do async without setting up and tearing down threads all the time:

1. You can have a "small" number of long-lived threads, and have them sleep when there's no work to do (this means that the OS will never schedule them for execution, so the resource drain is minimal). Then, when work arrives (i.e. Async method called), wake one of them up and tell it what needs to be done. Pleased to meet you, [managed thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx).
2. In Windows, the most efficient mechanism for async is [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which synchronizes access to I/O operations and allows a small number of threads to manage massive workloads.

Regarding multiple threads:

Having multiple threads is not bad for performance, *if*

- the number of threads is not excessive
- the threads do not oversaturate the CPU

If the number of threads is excessive then obviously we are taxing the OS with having to keep track of and schedule all these threads, which uses up global resources and slows it down.

If the threads are CPU-bound, then the OS will need to perform much more frequent context switches in order to maintain fairness, and context switches kill performance. In fact, with [user-mode threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682661.aspx) (which all highly scalable systems use -- think RDBMS) we make our lives harder just so we can avoid context switches.

**Update:**

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1285774/50079), which lends support to the position that you can't say how many threads are too much beforehand -- there are just too many unknown variables.

Comment: @Lazlo: I 'm no scalability expert. There are 1237 threads on my system right now, and it doesn't complain. Of course it's likely that >1000 of those are not runnable at any one time, but that's just an educated guess. **Edit**: of course all those threads use up just a few percent of CPU when I 'm idling.

Comment: The ideal state is to have one unblocked thread per CPU. So on a quad-core machine, you want to have 4 threads each going at 100%.  Anything more than that requires additional overhead.

Comment: I'm not sure how to concretely use a managed thread pool in a master server context. There would be no "idling" period, unless no one is connected. I'll start a new question with a more concrete approach (more code examples) and let people criticize them. I'll post the link here.

Comment: @Robert Levy But windows won't (at least without fiddling) allow one thread to starve a CPU/core entirely. I've found that multiple threads (2-3x per core, assume no contention) allow more "performance" overall -- actually coming down to "stealing" time from other threads in relationship.

Comment: correct,  the 'ideal' state is still 1 thread fully utilizing each core.  anything else requires overhead.  there is no way to really reach this ideal so the goal is to stay as close to it as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer is great.  As for the 'side question'... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law.   Amdel's law says that serial code quickly diminishes the gains to be had from parallel code.  We also know that thread coordination (scheduling, context switching, etc) is serial - so at some point more threads means there are so many serial steps that parallelization benefits are lost and you have a net negative performance.  This is tricky stuff.  That's why there is so much effort going into letting .NET manage threads while we define 'tasks' for the framework to decide what thread to run on.  The framework can switch between tasks much more efficiently than the OS can switch between threads because the OS has a lot of extra things it needs to worry about when doing so.

Comment: It's more than that.  Spilling the CPU cache happens in parallel on each core, but is still so VERY expensive that it is a major contributor to why threads>cores is bad for scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous work can be done *without* one-thread-per-connection or a thread pool with OS support for `select` or `poll` (and Windows supports this and it is exposed via [Socket.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx)). I am not sure of the performance on windows, but this is a very common idiom elsewhere.

One thread is the "pump" that manages the IO connections and monitors changes to the streams and then dispatches messages to/from other threads (conceivably 0 ... n depending upon model). Approaches with 0 or 1 additional threads may fall into the "Event Machine" category like twisted (Python) or POE (Perl). With >1 threads the callers form an "implicit thread pool" (themselves) and basically just offload the blocking IO.

There are also approaches like Actors, [Continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) or [Fibres](http://www.rubyinside.com/fibers-eventmachine-rack-performance-gains-3395.html) exposed in the underlying models of some languages which alter how the basic problem is approached -- don't wait, react.

Happy coding.

Comment: Absolutely true, but assuming a multicore machine (who doesn't have one these days?) and that the server is doing some computation for each client so that it's CPU bound, maximum throughput can only be achieved using multiple threads.  So while your answer described my preferred approach to multiple connections in general, it doesn't seem to work for this question.