# Which threading method is the most optimal for master server networking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking, asynchronous

Following this question, I decided to start with a more concrete approach, rather than being thrown theoretical and conceptual information I cannot integrate: [Are Socket.*Async methods threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359204/are-socket-async-methods-threaded)

The point is to keep fluidity for all the clients, while optimizing the server. This means asynchrony in a way or another, in order not to block the main operation.

Here are some methods I came up with. "Process" is an hypothetical method that handles the data received from the client. Consider this could take between 1-5ms usually, perhaps 500-2000ms for *rare* database calls.

**Using Socket.*Async and looping**

```
static void Main()
{
    Socket listener = new Socket(...);
    listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 555));

    List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>();

    SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

    while (true)
    {
        if (listener.AcceptAsync(e))
        {
            clients.Add(e.AcceptSocket);
        }

        foreach (Socket client in clients)
        {
            if (client.ReceiveAsync(e))
            {
                Process(e.Buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pros:

- One thread only!
- Rather simple to manage.

Cons:

- While(true): Too CPU intensive?
- Since all ops are following each other, they slow down all clients connected.

I assume this is somehow a good start, perhaps the best of my solutions. If I could mix in a thread pool, split the accept, the receive, and the process in different threads, we might be going somewhere.

**Using Socket.Begin*/End* and ManualResetEvent**

```
static class Server
{
    static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    static ManualResetEvent acceptDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main()
    {
        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 555));

        while (true)
        {
            acceptDone.Reset();

            listener.BeginAccept(OnAccept, null);

            acceptDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        acceptDone.Set();

        new Receiver(listener.EndAccept(ar));
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Receiver(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;

        new Thread
        (
            delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    receiveDone.Reset();

                    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);

                    receiveDone.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        ).Start();
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        receiveDone.Set();

        int received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        byte[] toProcess = new byte[received];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, toProcess, 0, received);
        Process(toProcess);
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Fully asynchronous, clients never slowed down by other operations.
- Using ManualResetEvents allows to stop the server nicely.

Cons:

- Way too many threads, 1 per client!
- Wasted processing time since all threads are blocked with reset events?

And finally a way of simplifying this solution, without manual reset events.

**Using Blocking Calls and manual threads**

```
static class Server
{
    static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    static void Main()
    {
        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 555));

        while (true)
        {
            new Receiver(listener.Accept());
        }
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    Socket socket;

    public Receiver(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;

        new Thread
        (
            delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int received = socket.Receive(buffer);
                    byte[] toProcess = new byte[received];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, toProcess, 0, received);
                    Process(toProcess);
                }
            }
        ).Start();
    }
}
```

**Using a Thread Pool**

I actually have no idea how to use one, could someone give me an example for it?

**Suggestions**

Probably that the solution isn't any of the ones in this post. How would you handle it?

As you can see, I used .*Async methods, Begin*/End* methods, and blocking methods, but all have relatively major cons.

Thanks in advance :) I can't wait to see S/O's code examples.

Comment: are you bound to C# fore your language or can you use other languages to simplify this task ?

Comment: @RobertPitt: Are you bound to your wife for your marriage or can you use other women to simplify this task?

Comment: Well it depends doesn't it, who does the job the best?

Comment: @RobertPitt: It was just a joke intended to convey my "fidelity" for a language I value and the fact to avoid using "easy ways out".

Comment: It's not about "the easy way out", it's about using the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `Begin/End` correctly. There is no need to wait on the events, let the framework handle this. Note that in [the MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx) the receive loop doesn't use an explicit event, although the accept loop does for ease of control and exposition.

```
static class Server
{
    static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    static void Main()
    {
        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 555));
        listener.BeginAccept(OnAccept, null);

        WaitUntilServerNeedsToShutdown () ;

        // worker threads will die because they are background
    }

    private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        new Receiver(listener.EndAccept(ar));
        listener.BeginAccept(OnAccept, null);
    }
}

class Receiver
{
    Socket socket;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    public Receiver(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        byte[] toProcess = new byte[received];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, toProcess, 0, received);

        // TODO: detect EOF and error conditions
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);

        // TODO: is it OK to process incomplete data?
        Process(toProcess);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, that's indeed much more logical. But isn't this still 1 thread per connection?